# Trouble deleting cases from a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I've been trying to delete the rows that have the value -9 in a certain column, but I haven't been successful at it.
Here's what I've tried:

```
ocupados.MONTO_DE_INGRESO_TOTAL.drop([-9])
```

but what I get is '[-9] not found in axis'

I know that -9 is a value in that column because "describe" shows that the min is -9.0000.
I've tried drop.([-9.000000]) and drop.([-9.000000], axis=0), but it didn't work either. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `drop` with the index of rows that match your condition:

```
ocupados.drop(ocupados[ocupados.MONTO_DE_INGRESO_TOTAL == -9].index, inplace=True)
```

Or keep rows that does not match condition:

```
ocupados = ocupados[ocupados.MONTO_DE_INGRESO_TOTAL != -9]
```